# how to find a sum using linq in a bson document using C#

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb

The sample collections structure is :-

```
{
 arr : [
       { "seq" : 2 },
       { "seq" : 4 }
       ]
}
```

The C# code i tried is

```
var maxTicketSeq = bsonTrans["arr"].AsBsonArray.Sum(m => (int)m["seq"]);
```

this is working fine...

But for this structure

```
{
"arr" : [

 { "name" : [{"seq" : 2 } , {"seq" : 5 }] },
 { "name" : [{"seq" : 2 } , {"seq" : 5 }] }

}
```

for this i need to find the sum of seq.

how to achieve this in linq query.

Actually that bsonDocument is similar to the one which i am getting as result of a mongo query.

Comment: is `"tickets"` a copy/paste error of `"arr"` here? also - you ask about "sum", but show a `Max` ...?

Comment: sorry copy/paste error..
in dat if put sum also its working fine.

Comment: i updated with that change. sorry for confusion

Comment: You'll likely want to use aggregation rather than locally retrieving all documents. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/sum/